# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException. Works fine in one class but throws error in another class

Tags: android, sqlite

I have went through many answers in stack overflow but nothing helps.My app gets data from SQL server through webservices and write to a local sqlite db. I can confirm that this pulls and stores data. My next step is to use pagination to display first ten rows and load more when user scrolls down.

I have got a class that represents the data of a sqlite record. I have got a function createRuns() to fetch first 10 records

public class Run  {

```
private int runid;
private int id;
private int Esky_no;
private int Adjusted;
private String Address;
private int Cust_No;
private String New;
private String Trusted;
private String Name;
private String Mobile;
private String Home;
private String Work;
private String PaymentType;
private String PaymentNote;
private String DeliveryTime;
private String DeliveryInstructions;
private String DriverNotes;
private String NoDeliveryReason;
private String IsDelivered;

public Run() {
}

public Run(int runid, int id, int Esky_no, int Adjusted, String Address, int Cust_No, String New, String Trusted, String Name, String Mobile, String Home, String Work, String PaymentType, String PaymentNote, String DeliveryTime, String DeliveryInstructions, String DriverNotes, String NoDeliveryReason, String IsDelivered) {
    this.runid = runid;
    this.id = id;
    this.Esky_no = Esky_no;
    this.Adjusted = Adjusted;
    this.Address = Address;
    this.Cust_No = Cust_No;
    this.New = New;
    this.Trusted = Trusted;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Mobile = Mobile;
    this.Home = Home;
    this.Work = Work;
    this.PaymentType = PaymentType;
    this.PaymentNote = PaymentNote;
    this.DeliveryTime = DeliveryTime;
    this.DeliveryInstructions = DeliveryInstructions;
    this.DriverNotes = DriverNotes;
    this.NoDeliveryReason = NoDeliveryReason;
    this.IsDelivered = IsDelivered;
}
public static List<Run> createRuns(int itemCount) {
    List<Run> runs = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    try {
        database=openDatabase("DriverPortalDB", null, OPEN_READONLY);
        //Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
        //if (con != null) {
        if (database != null) {
            int plusten = itemCount + 10;
            Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM RunsheetData where IsNewAndroid = '1' and id > '" + itemCount + "' and id <= '" + plusten + "'" , null);
            int count = c.getCount();
            while(c.moveToNext()){

                Run run = new Run(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)),
                        Integer.parseInt(c.getString(1)),
                        Integer.parseInt(c.getString(2)),
                        Integer.parseInt(c.getString(3)),
                        c.getString(4),
                        Integer.parseInt(c.getString(5)),
                        c.getString(6),
                        c.getString(7),
                        c.getString(8),
                        c.getString(9),
                        c.getString(10),
                        c.getString(11),
                        c.getString(12),
                        c.getString(13),
                        c.getString(14),
                        c.getString(15),
                        c.getString(16),
                        c.getString(17),
                        c.getString(18));
                runs.add(run);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return runs;
}
```

I have attached a screenshot of my error message.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSbaD.jpg

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I don't think `Context.MODE.Private` is a valid flag rather it should be one of `OPEN_READWRITE OPEN_READONLY CREATE_IF_NECESSARY and/or NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS`; at least according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29

Comment: @MikeT I agree with you. I changed the flag to OPEN_READONLY. but I got the same error.

Comment: ooops missed that the 1st parameter has to be the path rather than the database name.

Comment: Thanks @MikeT. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely with the folloiwng code:

```
database=openDatabase("DriverPortalDB", null, Context.MODE.Private);
```

The **first paramater** should be the **path** rather then just the **database name**, the second issue is that **Context.MODE.Private**, the **second parameter** is not one of the specified flags *(it may or may not correlate with the value from the specified flags)*. The specified flags are:-

- **OPEN_READWRITE**
- **OPEN_READONLY**
- **CREATE_IF_NECESSARY**
- and/or **NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS**.

[SQLiteDatabase 
public final class SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29)

Comment: P.S. **Context,Mode.Private** appears to resolve to 0 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE. **OPEN_READWRITE** also appears to resolve to 0 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29. So **Context.MODE.Private** would likely work.